# There are 98 working lightbulbs in a batch of 100, and 2 non-working ones. How many ways could a sample

Tags: probability, statistics, combinations

of 5 be selected that contain /at least/ 1 of the broken bulbs?

So far, I have tried only 1 method, as it's the only one I've been taught, but I don't know if I am doing it right.
I tried doing C(100,1)/C(100,5) but it just doesn't seem right. Is it? If it isn't, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

1) Total number of ways to choose a sample of $5$ bulbs from $100$= $100 \choose 5$.

2) Total number of ways to choose $5$ non defective bulbs= $98 \choose 5$- as there are $98$ non defective bulbs.

Now subtract $(2)$ from $1$ to get your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using subtraction (as described in another answer) is probably the best way to do this, but you could also break it up into two cases:

where you get exactly 1 defective bulb, and where you get both of the defective bulbs.

This approach gives an answer of $\displaystyle\binom{2}{1}\binom{98}{4}+\binom{2}{2}\binom{98}{3}$.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is the following one:

$\bullet$ Let's suppose that you want to have **exactly 1** non - working bulb.

Then, you need 4 working bulbs out of the 99 and 1 non-working bulb out of 2.

Then, the ways you can choose the 4 working bulbs are $\binom{98}{4}$ and the ways you can choose the non - working bulb are $\binom{2}{1}$.

So, the ways you can choose **exactly 1** non - working bulb and 4 working bulbs are: $\binom{98}{4} \cdot \binom 2 1$.

$\bullet$ Let's suppose that you want to have **exactly 2** non - working bulbs.

Then, the ways you can choose the 3 working bulbs are $\binom{98}{3}$ and the ways you can choose the 2  non - working bulbs are $\binom{2}{2}$.

So, the ways you can choose **exactly 2** non - working bulbs and 3 working bulbs are $\binom{98}{3} \cdot \binom 2 2$.

So, the ways you can choose **at least one**  non - working bulb are:

$\binom{98}{4} \cdot \binom 2 1+\binom{98}{3} \cdot \binom 2 2$